# DataGrid AddChild in Runspace

Tags: wpf, powershell, datagrid

I've created a PowerShell Runspace and wanted to populate a DataGrid from a CSV file. The code works fine without a Runspace, but not in it.

I think the error must be in this two lines, but I can't get it:

```
$csv = Import-Csv "C:\name.csv" -Delimiter ";" -Encoding UTF8 |
       Select-Object @{Name='USER';Expression={$_.USER}},`@{Name='ID';Expression={$_.ID}}
$csv | % { $syncHash.dgusers.AddChild($_) }
```

With this two lines in the code. The GUI won't show up.

The full code:

```cs
Add-Type -AssemblyName PresentationFramework

$syncHash = [hashtable]::Synchronized(@{})
$Runspace =[runspacefactory]::CreateRunspace()
$Runspace.ApartmentState = "STA"
$Runspace.ThreadOptions = "ReuseThread"
$Runspace.Open()
$Runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("syncHash", $syncHash)

$code = {
#Build the GUI
[xml]$xaml = @"
<Window
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        Title="UserList" Height="368" Width="525" WindowStyle="ToolWindow" Topmost="True" ResizeMode="NoResize">
    <Grid>
        <TabControl Name="tabControl" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="308" Margin="18,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="481">
            <TabItem Header="Lieferanten">
                <Grid Background="#ffffff">
                    <DataGrid Name="dgusers" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Margin="19,27,158,20">
                        <DataGrid.Columns>
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding ID}" Width="40" />
                            <DataGridTextColumn Header="USER" Binding="{Binding USER}" Width="233"/>
                        </DataGrid.Columns>
                    </DataGrid>
                </Grid>
            </TabItem>
        </TabControl>
    </Grid>
</Window>
"@

$reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)
$syncHash.Window=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load($reader)
$syncHash.Error = $Error

# XAML objects
$syncHash.dgusers = $syncHash.window.FindName("dgusers")

$csv = Import-Csv "C:\name.csv" -Delimiter ";" -Encoding UTF8 |
       Select-Object @{Name='USER';Expression={$_.USER}},`@{Name='ID';Expression={$_.ID}}
$csv | % { $syncHash.dgusers.AddChild($_) }


$syncHash.Window.ShowDialog()
$Runspace.Close()
$Runspace.Dispose()
}

$PSinstance1 = [powershell]::Create().AddScript($Code)
$PSinstance1.Runspace = $Runspace
$job = $PSinstance1.BeginInvoke()
```

Comment: You seems to be a spurious backtick after the comma in your `Select-Object` statement.

Comment: haha ... great! It worked! Thank you soo much!